# Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined in React Storm

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me in understanding what am i doing wrong here. I am new to JavaScript programming.I am getting this error:

Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

The code :

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Page extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h2>{this.props.currentPage.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.props.currentPage.slice(1)}</h2>
                <p>This is the {this.props.currentPage} page</p>
                {/* example of using chain methods inside the curly brackets to transform and concat string */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that `this.props.currentPage` is `undefined`

Comment: You probably want to use `this.state` instead of `this.props`. Also include a constructor along with a `this.setState()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can safeize the code:

```
  ((this.props.currentPage || "").charAt(0) || "").toUpperCase()
```